Inequality involving sums
Suppose I have positive numbers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k$ where each $0<\alpha_i<1$ and that they also sum 1:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i=1
\end{align}
Given $k$ positive numbers $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k$, I wonder if it is possible to find a constant $C$, independent of all $m_i$ and $\alpha_i$, such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i^2m_i^2\geq C \sum_{i=1}^k m_i^2 
\end{align}
If such a constant $C$ exists, how does it depend on $k$?

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

if you take $\alpha_1 = \frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ too large, the others $\alpha_i$ constants, $m_1$ too large and the others $m_i = 1$, we have $\sum\alpha_i^2 m_i^2 \gt \frac{N^2}{n^2}$. by choosing $N$ and $n$ large the desired inequality does not hold for any $C$!

There is no such $C$. Let's assume that your inequality holds for some $C$, independently of the $(m_i)_{1 \leq i \leq k}$ and $(\alpha_i)_{1 \leq i \leq k}$.
Then we would have
$$
C \leq \frac{\alpha_1^2 + \sum_{i=2}^{k}\alpha_i^2 \frac{m_i^2}{m_1^2}}{1 + \sum_{i=2}^{k}\frac{m_i^2}{m_1^2}}.
$$
Since this inequality needs to be true for arbitrarily large $m_1$, taking the limit gives
$ C \leq \alpha_1^2 $.
But clearly, we can also choose $\alpha_1$ to be arbitrarily small, such that we would have $C\leq 0$.
